# How do I take an Iterable of one class and turn it into an Iterable of another class?

Tags: java

I have an iterable of one class: `Iterable<ClassA> classAIterable`. I have a second class like this:

```
public class ClassB {
    private final ClassA classA;
    public ClassB(ClassA a) {
        this.classA = a;
    }
}
```

I would like to take every `ClassA` object in `classAIterable` and turn it into a `ClassB` object that contains a `ClassA` object and put them into an iterable of `ClassB`.

How would I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `Iterable` to a `Stream` by accessing the `Spliterator`, by using [`StreamSupport.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-).  In the `Stream` you can map the elements from `ClassA` to `ClassB`, then collect them into a `List`, which is `Iterable`.

```
Iterable<ClassB> iterB = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
    .map(ClassB::new)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If my `ClassB` constructor takes more arguments, how do I pass those in?

Comment: You can use a lambda expression instead the constructor reference, e.g. `a -> new ClassB(a, other, args)`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it might not be suitable in your case, but as a variant of solution:

1) U can create interface:

```
interface interfaceC {
    }
```

2) And implement it in both `ClassA` and `ClassB`:

```
class ClassA implements interfaceC {        
    }

class ClassB implements interfaceC {        
    }
```

3) And then use iterable of `interfaceC`

```
class classIterable implements Iterable<interfaceC> {
        private List<interfaceC> internalList = null;
    }
```

Might work for u